# How to overcome http 429 error to send more API requests?

Tags: reactjs, http, http-proxy

Im currently working on a React app which sends http get request to an API to display on my webpage. However, The server returns HTTP error 429 if I send about 20/30 requests within an hour. I was thinking of proxying the http requests so as to maximise the number of API requests I can make to the API. Firstly, Can it be done? If yes, How can I go about doing so in React or are there any other solutions? Thanks a ton for your help in advance:)

Comment: You're asking how to work around an API's rate limit?

Comment: I would say so. I'm sending a get request to a website which does not require any key and the json file can be viewed when I key in the website into the browser normally.

Comment: Do you have control at the api server? If not, create a proxy and cache it

Comment: Nope, I do not have control. How can I go about creating a proxy and cache it? Would appreciate if you can point me in the right direction to get started.